Can Britain revoke the independence of a former colony?
In the Westminster legal system, is it possible to revoke the independence of a former colony? And if so, what is the correct procedure?

In theory, pass a law saying they're no longer independent. Afterwards the country which just got their independence revoked will have a good laugh, tell them to get lost, and possibly launch some sort of diplomatic sanctions.
If the country passing the law tries to actually make good on it, expect most other countries in the world to tell them to get lost as well.
Practically speaking, independence isn't something you can really revoke, barring military invasion. After all, by making a country independent you're implicitly letting go of your claim on them.
The UK and certain other countries in the Commonwealth are a bit of a special case, since they still have the British king as their nominal head of state (as noted by @Steve Melnikoff in the comments, not all Commonwealth countries do though). I imagine it still wouldn't work though, and would probably just end with the country in question leaving the Commonwealth. Though this doesn't really apply to the USA, since they were never part of of the Commonwealth (as noted by @Emil Jeřábek), and rather famously (and somewhat violently) rejected the British Monarch during their war of independence.
In the end, the UK and USA are separate, independent countries, and the UK has no legal power to revoke said independence. The only way to force that issue would be outright war, and I'm pretty sure everyone knows who'd win that one.

The US could not have possibly left the Commonwealth, as the former is 150 years older than the latter.

Most members of the Commonwealth don't have the King as their head of state; that only applies to the 15 Commonwealth Realms.

Thanks, incorporated it in the answer!

I'm downvoting because this is dismissive of the UK's ability to invade other countries and impose its will by military force. Maybe they can't do that to the US, but if they were to tell, e.g., Sudan that they're coming back to recolonize the country, I'd suspect Sudan will take the threat seriously (as opposed to "have a good laugh and tell them to get lost").

@Allure - Their official statements would still dismiss it as a ridiculous idea, so I think the answer is correct. Besides, this question, silly as it is, is about political strategies. Obviously, invasion is always an option (and the answer mentions it).


In the Westminster legal system, what is the correct procedure for revoking the independence of a former colony which is unable to govern?

First of all, most colonies became independent, because Britain was unable to govern. More precisely, the financial, human and political expense of holding onto colonies outweighed their usefulness.
Secondly, we also have to be careful about what we mean by "colony" - various protectorates, mandates, concessions, and treaties of special relationship are just euphemisms for "colony", palatable to western public, but often viewed as colonizing by the peoples concerned. Lords of the Desert: The Battle Between the United States and Great Britain for Supremacy in the Modern Middle East is an excellent and accessible account of how Britain was squeezed out of its possessions in the Middle East, although Palestine, Egypt, Iran and Yemen are probably not what the OP meant by colonies.
The examples given above allow to point out several obstacles to reclaiming a colony:

It is still too costly, and presents too few advantages
When a colony became an independent state, such a reclamation would constitute a violation of this state' sovereignty (aka aggression.)
The stronger independent states would resist - politically and militarily.
The weaker ones are "protected" by another power - most likely US, Russia or China, so there will be opposition from this power.
Finally, there may be colonies that are still de facto controlled by Britain, despite their officially independent status - if this works, what's the point of reclaiming them?

For purely legal aspect it is probably better to inquire in teh Law community.
